# Office365 アカウントで BizRobo(Kapow) へのログインが出来ない

Tags: windows

KapowでOffeice365ログインしようとしたのですが、
普通にメールアドレスとパスワードを入力してサインインボタンをクリックしても、
Redirecting...で止まり、ログインできません。
実はログインできているのかもと思い、outlook.office365.comなどを表示しようとしても、
やはりログイン画面に飛ばされてしまいます。

いきなり入り口で詰まってしまい困っています。
対応策をご存知の方、ご教授願います。

Answer (score 0):

Robot個別のConfiguration(左から4つ目のロボットボタンから)からDefault OptionをConfigurationするボタンでAll LoadingタブのUsername,Passwordを設定する。
パスワード変更都度、Robotファイルを差し替えなければならないので、ロボット化するのは運用面では不向きと考えられる。

Answer (score 0):

Office365はlogin robotを予防するためこういうになってると思います。
それは違うと思う人は教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「Redirecting...で止まってログインできない」現象と今回の回答が私には明確に関連性がわかりませんでした。もうちょっと詳細に回答できませんか？

Comment: Office365はロボットを禁止している。なのでKapowでのログインはできない。ということではないでしょうか？